# How can I change my system locale in windows 10?

Tags: java, windows

I was having issues with my current system locale. I do not want to use some special locale code every time I run my java program. So I took the route suggested by this link https://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml. I followed all the instructions over there and restarted my computer. I went to the same settings and can see that my language for non-Unicode programs is eng-us. But still whenever I run a java program from the command line or from eclipse, I'm getting an error when I use dot as my decimal delimeter as in 3.14 (according to my current locale I should use 3,14)

Comment: No matter the program you use, string representation of numbers only considers system locale as it's translation source. If you are writing programs that want to consider different locales you should do that manually in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood you, so my answer may be inappropriate.

The settings in your *mentioned link* are related only to the **general locale settings** of your *Windows operating system*. Applications (as *Java*) may decide *to use or to not use* these settings. But ...

Locale settings are **NOT applied** for writing numbers in **programming languages** in general - they accept numbers in you *code* - in spite of a chosen programming language and locale - *only with decimal point* (`.`).

A good examples are applications with "two faces" - *user* environment and *programming* environment, e. g. Excel. In the *user environment* Excel accepts (and even *requires*) numbers with the comma (`,`) as a decimal separator - in appropriate locales, of course - even in *formulas*, but in its VBA programming language you are forced to use period (`.`), however.

The **output** of your *Java program* may be, of course, formatted for your - or other desired - locale.